# Function doesn't print the integers inside her

Tags: clojure

I'm a begginer with clojure and i were reading a book that contained that function:

```
(defn illustrative-function [] (+ 1 304) 30 "joe")
```

And if you invoke that function without an argument it returns only "joe", as you can see:

```
(illustrative-function )
=> "joe"
```

My question:

Why the numbers inside the function aren't printed? 305 and 30? Even when i use and argument (and a parameter) it doesn't return nothing:

```
(defn illustrative-function [x] x (+ 1 304) 30 "joe")
=> #'dev-projects.core/illustrative-function

(illustrative-function 3)
=> "joe"

(illustrative-function [3])
=> "joe"
```

Can someone explain why does that happens?

Why the integers and the arguments are not printed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of a `defn` is wrapped in an `do`.  `do` allows you to execute
multiple instructions usually for side-effects.  The last statement in
the `do` is the return.  So this looks like this:

```
(defn illustrative-function 
  [] 
  (do
    (+ 1 304) ; no-op
    30        ; no-op
    "joe"))   ; return
```

`(+ 1 304)` is read and calculated, then thrown aways.  `30` is just
read and thrown away.  `"joe"` then is the return of `do` and by that
the return of the function.

If you want to "print" something, you have to explicitly `print` it.
E.g. replace `30` with `(println 30)`.  Also note, that in the REPL, the
return value is printed into the REPL - if you call that function from
somewhere else, nothing is printed unless you print explicitly.